# why my laptop can't use wireless charging technology?

Tags: battery-charging, iphone, electricity, laptop, wireless-charging

we start to deal with wireless charging technology in recent years with the booming of smart phones
why wasn't it possible with laptops?
does the smart phone's battery differ from laptop's?

Comment: Take a look at existing wireless charging reference designs, in particular the wattage and typical efficiencies. Then take a look at the specs of your laptop charger. It's not impossible, but laptops require quite a bit of power to charge quickly. A netbook, maybe...

Comment: Who said it can't?

Comment: It's actually cheaper and in almost every way better to use a docking station. Even for phones I still believe it's better to use a docking station, also in almost every way.

Comment: [Who said they don't?](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/07/12/dell_latitude_7285_wireless_charging_two_in_one_pc/)

Comment: It's not a matter of *not being possible*, it's a matter of *not being practical* or *not being cost-effective*. Watch Dave Jones' EEVblog videos about UBeam.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wireless charging techniques for charging laptop computers but you won't be very happy with the current state of the technology.

The wireless charging systems that I've worked with for smartphones are good for maybe 10 Watts (but often less). That's okay for a smartphone and most will reach full charge in a few hours.

The smallest laptop charger for a medium-sized laptop is at 60 Watts. Higher-end laptops can have chargers rated at 135 Watts or more.

Many (most?) laptops need 20 to 50 Watts just to operate. Your little 10 Watt wireless charger can't even keep up with required power to operate the laptop, let alone have enough energy for charging the battery.

Answer (score 0):

To charge a laptop, well technology wise it's not a problem. But wireless charging have some disadvantages that inflict on the usage, like:

Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_charging

> **Slower charging** – Due to the lower efficiency, devices take longer to charge when supplied power is the same amount.
>
> **More expensive** – Inductive charging also requires drive electronics and coils in both device and charger, increasing the complexity and cost of manufacturing.
>
> **Inconvenience** - When a mobile device is connected to a cable, it can be moved around (albeit in a limited range) and operated while charging. In most implementations of inductive charging, the mobile device must be left on a pad to charge, and thus can't be moved around or easily operated while charging.